# How to integrate QuickSort on a vector of strings where I must sort for length of the string?

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to implement quick sort to order strings based on their lengths. Something is wrong with what I am doing and I can't for the life of me figure out what's incorrect. I was hoping another set of eyes could check out my code and figure out where I went wrong.

```
void justAQuickieSort(int left, int right)
{
//left and right given by left = 0 and right = copy.begin();
    if(left < right)
    {
    int part = partition(left, right);
    justAQuickieSort(left, part - 1);
    justAQuickieSort(part + 1, right);
    }
}

int partition(int left, int right) {

    string temp = " ";
    const int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;

    // move the mid point value to the front.

    temp = copy[mid];
    copy[mid] = copy[left];
    copy[left] = temp;
    int i = left + 1;
    int j = right;
    while (i <= j) {

        while(i <= j && copy[i].size() <= copy[mid].size()) {
            i++;
        }

        while(i <= j && copy[j].size() > copy[mid].size()) {
            j--;
        }

        if (i < j) {
            cout << "here" << endl;
            temp = copy[i];
            copy[i] = copy[j];
            copy[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    temp = copy[i-1];
    copy[i-1] = copy[left];
    copy[left] = temp;
    return i-1;
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Some advice:  If you're going to write your own sort, I suggest you write a templated version that sorts on the type given.  Once you do that (say with simple `int` types), factor out the part that does the comparison into a separate function that takes two arguments and returns `true` or `false` depending on whether arg1 < arg2.  Once you have that working, then all you need to do is change the function to return `true` or `false`, comparing the lengths of the two args.  That is how `std::sort` organizes things, and even C's `qsort` does things this way (only not typesafe).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie If I did do that, where exactly would I put that in my quick sort?

Answer (score 0):

One error is here:

```
while(i <= j && copy[i].size() <= copy[mid].size()) {
    i++;
}

while(i <= j && copy[j].size() > copy[mid].size()) {
    j--;
}
```

you compare with 'mid' despite having moved 'mid' to 'left' it should be

```
while(i <= j && copy[i].size() <= copy[left].size()) {
    i++;
}

while(i <= j && copy[j].size() > copy[left].size()) {
    j--;
}
```